# Threaded Binary tree implementation from binary tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I am working on assignment for school. It manly consists of a method that takes as input a binary tree and returns a double threaded tree. Eg(if left child = null then left child will be connected with preceding inorder parent and if right child = null the it will link to its inorder succesor. Now I have an idea for the implementation...

I iterate recursively trough the original BINARY tree and store into an array the inorder traversal. Now, because my teachers implementation requires that threaded trees be a different class from binary. I must traverse again trough the binary tree and convert each node from binaryNode to threadedNode thus having at the end  a "duplicate" of the initial BinaryTree  but as Threadedtree type. After I do this I traverse again trough this threadedTree and whenever i see a null left or right child I refer to the inorder arraylist  and find the threads.

Now as you might have noticed this is extremely inefficient, i am essentially traversing the tree 3 times. My professor has stated that this could be done recursively with only one traversal, essentially converting to threadedNode and finding the threads all at once. I have tried multiple ways but i can not find one that works. Does anyone have any kind of tip or some way i can implement it? Thanks

This is the method as specified by the instructor

```
public static <T> ThreadedNode<T> thread(BinaryNode<T> root)
{
   //threads a binary tree
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructor is correct.  One traversal is sufficient.

Traverse the original binary tree, creating new `ThreadedNode`s as you walk this tree.

```
public static <T> ThreadedNode<T> thread(BinaryNode<T> root) {
    // We'll be keeping track of the "previous" node as we go, so use
    // a recursive helper method.  At first, there is no previous.
    return threadHelper(root, null);
}

private static <T> ThreadedNode<T> threadHelper(BinaryNode<T> n, ThreadedNode<T> previous) {

    // Create a new threaded node from the current root.  Note that the threaded nodes
    // are actually created in "preorder".  Assume the ThreadedNode constructor sets
    // the left, right, threadLeft, and threadRight fields to null.
    ThreadedNode<T> t = new ThreadedNode<T>(n.getData());

    // First go down the left side, if necessary.
    if (n.getLeft() != null) {
        // If there is a left child we have to descend.  Note that as we go down the
        // left side the previous doesn't change, until we start "backing up".
        t.left = threadHelper(n.getLeft(), previous);
        previous = t.left;
    } else {
        // If there is no left child, connect our left thread to the previous.
        t.threadLeft = previous;
    }

    // Now before we go down the right side, see if the previous
    // node (it will be in the left subtree) needs to point here.
    if (previous != null && previous.right == null) {
        previous.threadRight = t;
    }

    if (n.getRight() != null) {
        // If there is a right child we can descend the right.  As we go down we
        // update previous to the current node.  We do this just by passing the current
        // node as the second parameter.
        t.right = threadHelper(n.getRight(), t);
    } else {
        // No right child, no worries.  We'll hook up our thread-right pointer
        // later.
    }
    return t;
}
```

Consider the tree (A (B (D) ()) C).  The first node you hit in an inorder traversal is D.  There is no previous node.  So save D as previous.  Then the next node you hit is B.  The previous node was D, which had no right child, so add a threaded right pointer from D to B.  Then set previous to B and continue.  Next you hit A.  B had no right child, so add a threaded right link from B to A.  A has a right child so continue, setting previous to A.  The next node is C.  C has no left child, so add a threaded left link from C to the current value of previous, which is A.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but remember that I also must create a new threadedNode for each node visited since there is a difference between binaryNode and threadedNode. So I must build the ThreadedTree while doing the inorder traversal of the initial Binarytree.

Comment: Definitely!  Emit threaded nodes as you go.  I can update my answer if you like.

Comment: I understand your implementation, there is a small problem with your code (right null children does not seem to thread) but now I know where to start. Thank you

Comment: Oh sorry I should have tested it.  Let me know if you get stuck.  Glad it is a starting point, though.

Comment: I think I am done, I have to test with different trees to make sure. I resorted to using recursion but aside from having the holder for the previous element I also had a stack that would allow me to find the next element and append it to the right children before the recursive call ended. Can't thank you enough for your help. Have a Gn.

Comment: I hate to butt-in like this, but it seems we might know each other. 

However, it seems as though this method sets the left thread of the leftmost node to itself, and the right thread of the rightmost node to itself instead of null.

I thought that maybe `prev` would take care of that, but while working it out I can't come to any other conclusion. Am I tracing it wrong?

Comment: The intent is for the leftmost node (the first in the inorder traversal) to have a _null left thread pointer_, not to point to itself.  If you create a threaded tree from a single node tree, both the left thread and right thread pointers will stay null. I may have time later to actually implement the method.  Sorry again for posting an untested method.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Since a `boolean` is used to test for thread existence, it seems that the left/right pointers are still null; the threads are simply set to `true`. That is easily remedied. Thank you for clarification. 

I just re-read your statement below the code, and it seems I did trace it wrong on the way back (when `previous` gets actually set). Thank you.

Comment: Ray is correct. The only two nodes that will have null pointers are the first and last. With that being said... I thought I had fixed the problem (The tree has the correct threads), but due to my use of a stack, some of these nodes are not actually the nodes but only a shallow copy of them.

Comment: I seem to have a slightly different issue... for trees of height >2, some right nodes do not get threaded to their respective successors. Hopefully I can figure it out in time, but working through all these recursive calls is just mind-breaking.

Comment: Yeah I blew it.  I got exactly the situation you described at http://ideone.com/MVwSd.  I will try again tomorrow.  The problem is in the line `if (previous != null && previous.right == null)` The second not null check should be on the node from which previous was made, NOT on `previous.right` itself!

Comment: This is proving to be really hard.  [This article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/spe.4380151002/abstract) claims to have a linear time algorithm for threading binary trees _with no additional storage_ but I have not read it. Surely the OP's original algorithm is linear time, albeit with multiple passes and extra storage.  I've also tried several approaches to creating all the threads in *one pass* but it seems that doing so requires a stack (at least) of extra storage.

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the second trip of traversal that you mention in your method. You could convert the nodes from BinaryNode to  ThreadedNode on the fly. You'd still need to traverse twice, I think, for the inorder traversal, and for finding the threads and converting it to aThreadedTree.

For conversion on the fly, you could use the method that your instructor has given.

HTH!

Comment: What do you mean by converting on the fly?